# Why is this .obj loader not drawing anything but the included .obj?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opengl, glut

I've been adapting a tutorial on .obj file loading on the windows system to glut.

The thing's not drawing anything except the "Foot.obj" file that the tutorial included and I'm going kinda nuts trying to figure out where's the fault. I'd appreciate [a look into the code](http://www.filedropper.com/ripobj_2).

To try loading a different .obj just change the line

```
#define FILE_NAME_1 "Foot.obj"
```

in `Main.cpp`. I included the .obj files I've been trying to load into the VS project.

Comment: And what happens when you change the loaded obj file?  This question lacks info.

Comment: @Goz: "The thing's not drawing a thing except the "Foot.obj" file that the tutorial included" means it isn't drawing other obj files.

Comment: Have you debugged the data load to see if data is actually getting loaded?  Can you see where its failing?  Is the data getting loaded and still nothing is drawn?  This question lacks info.

Comment: @Goz: The data is getting loaded, it isn't being drawn.

Comment: apparently I missed the glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); and glLoadIdentity(); declarations before gluPerspective(); http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=591112

Comment: I don't get why it doesn't draw the cube still and why did it draw the Foot without the glMatrixMode call,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your OBJ loader handles n>3-gons (`violin_case.obj`), face elements without a texture index (`head.obj`, `chess.obj`), or face elements with the full complement of indexes (`pTierra.obj`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll rewrite the whole thing.